# Jest TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a setup for an external application and start it within a const, then put it in the **const allowAppInstance** the configuration of the appConfig

```
export const setupRemote = () => {
  if (isRemoteAvailable) {
    try {
      ...

      const allowAppInstance = SetupConfig.start(remoteInstance);

      return {
        allowAppInstance,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};
```

here I export

```
export const appSetupConfig = () => setupRemote().allowAppInstance;
```

in the component, I get this setup and put it in a const

```
import { appSetupConfig } from '.../myapp'

      useEffect(() => {
        const allowAppInstance = appSetupConfig();
    
        ...the rest of code
    
      }, []);
```

the application works, **but when I run the tests, jest doesn't let it pass, it causes this error:**

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowAppInstance' of null

  43 | };
  44 | 
> 45 | export const appSetupConfig = () => setupRemote().allowAppInstance;
```

Is there any way to mock **allowAppInstance** to pass the test? I really don't know what to do and what am I doing wrong

Comment: What is the value of `isRemoteAvailable` when unit testing? I think that being falsey could cause `window.setup` to not be defined, and eventually exported for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the setup property manually with mock function at the top of your test:
but depending on how your app uses allowAppInstance you may need to do some extra work.

```
const setup = {appConfig: jest.fn();}
Object.defineProperty(window, 'setup', setup);
```

Comment: Hello, I removed the const from window to try to improve and now the test is pointing me to another error, do you know how to help me?

Comment: Hello , yes you still need to mock the myApp module:

import { appSetupConfig } from '../myapp';
jest.mock('../myapp', () => ({
  appSetupConfig : jest.fn()
}))

Comment: I think you should remove the semicolon after `jest.fn()`